# Django: Perform GROUP BY over a view queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-annotate

I need to perform group by over a queryset of objects already filtered by standard django filters in order to filter by how many objects in queryset are related to same foreign key object. My code now (does not work):

```
class CustomerTicketsViewSet(AbstractViewSet):
    queryset = CustomerTicket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerTicketSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)

        tr2smp = int(self.request.GET.get('tickets_related_to_same_topic_gte', False))
        if self.action == "list" and tr2smp:
             topics_queryset = queryset.values('topic').annotate(tickets_to_same_mp=Count('topic')) #does not work
             queryset = ..... #filter tickets queryset somehow based on topics_queryset
        return queryset
```

If I filtered over all objects, I could have used

```
CustomerTicket.objects.values('topic').annotate(Count('topic'))
```

but how can I do the same thing with `QuerySet`?

Comment: `queryset.values('topic').annotate(Count('topic'))`

Comment: @Marco tried, what I get is `<QuerySet [{'topic': 2, 'topic__count': 1}, {'topic 2, 'topic__count': 1}, {'topic': 1, 'topic__count': 1}]>`

Comment: What means "does not work?" Errors, empty, ...... Also, debug if your queryset from super() function still contains all objects you need to filter/annotate/... Otherwise you need to hook in earlier.

Comment: @Marco I get `<QuerySet [{'topic': 2, 'topic__count': 1}, {'topic 2, 'topic__count': 1}, {'topic': 1, 'topic__count': 1}]>`, but i need to get `<QuerySet [{'topic': 2, 'topic__count': 2}, {'topic': 1, 'topic__count': 1}]>`

Comment: Try adding a `order_by()` at the end: `queryset.values('topic').annotate(Count('topic')).order_by()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `order_by()` to the end of your query:

```
queryset.values('topic').annotate(Count('topic')).order_by()
```

An interesting documentation about the usage of `values()` together with an annotation/aggregation can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values